# Interpreting bounding box in gis

Tags: python-3.x, geolocation, gis, raster

I am trying to understand geo static analysis

```
test_img_msk = "http://oin-hotosm.s3.amazonaws.com/5a95f32c2553e6000ce5ad2e/0/10edab38-1bdd-4c06-b83d-6e10ac532b7d.tif"

test_img_msk_rast = rasterio.open(test_img_msk)
print('test imag mask bounds ', test_img_msk_rast.bounds)

from rio_tiler.io import COGReader
with COGReader(test_img_msk) as cog:
    print(cog.info())
```

Above code output is shown below

```
output 1: test imag mask bounds  BoundingBox(left=683715.3266400001, bottom=1718548.5702, right=684593.2680000002, top=1719064.90736)

output 2: bounds=BoundingBox(left=-61.287001876638215, bottom=15.537756794450583,
                   right=-61.27877967704677, top=15.542486503997608)
                  center=(-61.28289077684249, 15.540121649224096, 16)
                  minzoom=16 maxzoom=22
                  band_metadata=[('1', {}), ('2', {}), ('3', {})]
                  band_descriptions=[('1', ''), ('2', ''), ('3', '')]
                  dtype='uint8' nodata_type='None'
                  colorinterp=['red', 'green', 'blue'] 
                  scale=None offset=None colormap=None 
                  overviews=[2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64] 
                  count=3 height=11666 width=19836 driver='GTiff'
```

My question is what is relation between bounding box `left=683715.3266400001 and left=-61.287001876638215` in output 2.
How to interpert this? Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

Your dataset `test_img_msk` has a projected coordinate system, [EPSG:32620](https://epsg.io/32620) to be specific which uses coordinate units of meters.

The second bounding box seems to be in a different coordinate system, likely a geographic coordinate system, where the coordinate units are decimal degrees.

So in the end, your `left` boundary is the same location, just in a different coordinate system.

For more info on projected vs geographic coordinate system, [check this article](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-pro/mapping/gcs_vs_pcs/).

**Edit**:

Looking at the [source code of `COGReader.info`](https://github.com/cogeotiff/rio-tiler/blob/ccf8418e49146a64ba27a43d99f727e38c60ccbd/rio_tiler/io/cogeo.py#L103) reveals that the bounding box coordinates are transformed from the native projection to the GCS WGS84 using `transform_bounds`.

Comment: thanks for input. How can I check what coordinate system second bounding box is referring.

Comment: thanks now with provided information i able to make sense of output